# Codeigniter routes and mod rewrite

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

for some reasons i've been having problems with mod rewrite, i have the index.php removed from the url ok but when i try to do the same for profiles it shows some contact webmaster page.
Now i'm taking the routes option but i have a little problem.

```
My url is http://website.com/user/profile/user_profile/username
```

I have this in my routes

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = 'user/profile/user_profile';
```

So when i type in website.com/profile/username, it works fine. My question is, what if i want to get rid of the /profile as well and have website.com/username, how do it go about it with routes?

Just incase, i might as well put my trail with modrewrite on here so all you brilliant minds can tell me where i'm going wrong.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|javascript|cron|sit-env|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|javascript|sit-env|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|javascript|cron|sit-env|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|javascript|sit-env|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)([\/]?)$ /user/profile.php/user_profile/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yikes. Some method will never get evoke or some user may never see his profile.

Comment: The answer below already explained it.

Comment: I left a comment there, check it. And what do you mean by some users may never see their profile?

Comment: your expected route directly collides with codeigniters controller/method. Out of these two, only one will run (whichever is at the top). If your custom rule is at the top, some controller/metods will never run (lets say you had a controler named `help` and a user named `help`. Which one will get the priority?). Or if you put custom rule at last, in the above example, the user `help` will never be able to see his profile and will be directed to `help` controller. **In short,** it is a very bad idea.

Comment: Ah i see, i didn't think of that to be perfectly honest. Don't worry though, do you know anyway to do it especially with the mod rw option. My solution for your scenario would be to put all my controller names in an array and make any of the controller names unavailable to users when chosing their usernames and since you can't call a method without calling the controller first, it should be cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply used the `404_override` method to capture any routes not already defined in CodeIgniter and then done a database look up before showing the 404 page.

My example is actually for a CMS however it could easily be changed to suit your requirement.

```
public function error_404()
{
    $Path = trim(uri_string(), '/');
    $this->load->model('page_model');
    $Page = $this->page_model->GetByPath($Path);
    if(empty($Page))
    {
        $ViewData = array
        (
            'PageTitle' => 'Error 404'  
        );
        $this->load->view('error_404', $ViewData);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $ViewData = array
        (
            'PageTitle' => $Page->Title,
            'Keywords' => $Page->Keywords,
            'Description' => $Page->Description,
            'CurrentPage' => $Page->Path,
            'Page' => $Page
        );
        $this->load->view('generic', $ViewData);
    }
}
```

Within my `application/config/routes.php` file, I simply put

```
$route['404_override'] = 'controller/error_404';
```

replacing `controller` with the controller that contains the `error_404` action.

You could use the segments collection to find the username passed to `www.domain.com/username` failing that, in line with your original request:

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = 'user/profile/user_profile/$1';
```

The above will route `www.domain.com/profile/abc123` to `www.domain.com/user/profile/user_profile/abc123`

Hope this helps?

Comment: Simply brilliant, excatly what i was looking for. Thanks sooo much.

Answer (score 0):

If you go the routes way, you could have it like this.

```
$route['(:any)/'] = 'user/profile/user_profile';
```

But be aware that rules are evaluated top to bottom. Keep it at the end, so if none of your site routes work, it will try to redirect it to the  user_profile controller.

The main con you have with this is that any strange url that your users run will be interpreted as a possible user. And if someone named *forum* wants to see his profile he'll probably get redirected to a forum if theres one.

Comment: Thanks for this but i really don't want website.com/anything to redirect to user profiles, that feels like a hack. I thought of it but i would like if only usernames were directed to their respective profiles.